# Why bit(1) returns chars 0x00 and 0x01 instead of 0x30 '0' and 0x31 '1'?

Tags: php, mysql

[According to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-type.html), `bit(1)` is a numeric field type. Then why using PHP 5.6 I'm receiving 0x00 and 0x01 chars?

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demo` (
    `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `test` bit(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `demo` (`id`, `test`) VALUES (1, b'0'), (2, b'1');
```

Test code:

```
$q = mysql_query("select * from demo");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    if ($row['test'] === chr(0x00)) {
        echo '0x00' . PHP_EOL;
    } elseif ($row['test'] === chr(0x01)) {
        echo '0x01' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    if ((bool) $row['test'] === true) {
        echo 'true' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'false' . PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Result:

```
0x00
true
0x01
true
```

I'm using PHP 5.6.9 with MySQL 5.5.44.

Comment: because `'0'` is an ascii character, while `0` is a bit set to "false".

Comment: @MarcB: Okay, then why `(bool) $row['test']` returns `true` for both rows?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chr(0x00) is an odd edge case in php:

```
chr(0x00) == true    -> true
chr(0x00) === true   -> false
chr(0x00) == false   -> false
chr(0x00) === false  -> false
empty(chr(0x00))     -> false
strlen(chr(0x00))    -> 1
(int)(chr(0x00))     -> 0
(bool)(chr(0x00))    -> true
var_dump(chr(0x00))  -> string(1) ""
```

it LOOKS like it should be false, but since it's not an empty string and not an integer 0/boolean false, you get this "unexpected" behavior.

Similarly for 0x01:

```
chr(0x01) == true    -> true
chr(0x01) === true   -> false
chr(0x01) == false   -> false
chr(0x01) === false  -> false
empty(chr(0x01))     -> false
strlen(chr(0x01))    -> 1
(int)(chr(0x01))     -> 0
(bool)(chr(0x01))    -> true
var_dump(chr(0x01))  -> string(1) ""
```